# Intern is not showing Code Coverage for Browser Tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dojo, code-coverage, intern

I have a sample project that I am using to write Unit Tests for Dojo modules before moving our to my main project. I have tests that are successfully running in node and chrome environments, but the coverage report is only reporting coverage for the tests executed in the node environment.

Below is a link to the sample project. Does anyone have any ideas why the code coverage report is not showing the metrics for TestModule_Dijit.js file specifically?

[SampleProject.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17DR58o4HSAAGpGmDsQ_V4isJ9sTlPFtv)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I tried your sample project, and it appears to be working fine. At least, when running Intern I see coverage reports for both the browser and Node.

Note that coverage is only gathered for browser tests that are managed Intern running in Node. In other words, tests run when you call `intern` from the command line will collect coverage, whether they're run in Node or in a browser. Tests run using the browser client, where you manually browse to `http://localhost:9000/__intern/`, will *not* collect coverage.

Unrelated to the original question, I noticed that you're gathering coverage data for your tests rather than the source files. In general, coverage is most meaningful for the source since the point of test coverage data is to show how much of your application code is being exercised by the tests (not how much of the test code itself is running).

Comment: First a clarification, then a question. I stripped out a ton of stuff from an actual project to create this sample project. So "TestModule_Dijit and "TestModule_Model" are actually source files which is what I am attempting to get coverage on, I just have them in a tests directory because they are a sample I'm going to remove.

As for the question, I am able to get the tests to run successfully, but when I run the tests (using the `intern` command) I still see the following output for the chrome tests:

`No unit test coverage for chrome 65.0.3325.181 on Windows NT`